# I'm new in stl c++, someone can explain [](int x)?

Tags: c++, stl

```
is_partitioned(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](int x)
    { return x%2==0;})? cout << "Vector is partitioned": cout << "Vector is not partitioned";
    cout << e
```

ndl;

I'm unable to understand this code due to `[](int x)`. please help

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on the proposed answer below?

Answer (score 6):

The `[](int x)` is actually just a part of the unnamed [lambda function object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
// Return true if x is divisible by 2, false otherwise
[] (int x) { return x%2 == 0; } // lambda that acts as a predicate
```

- `[]` denotes a **capture list**
- `(int x)` is a **parameter list**
- `{...}` part is the **body**

*Where the later two are just like in regular functions.*

You supply this function *(function object)* as a predicate to the algorithm `is_partitioned`, so to have a custom predicate. Note, that the `is_partitioned`, in this case, has the following form:

```
is_partitioned(first, last, predicate); // Where the predicate is the lambda
```

For more information, refer to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).